# While installing the setup for tensorflow object detection api, in the last step, I am facing the following issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmake, object-detection, pyarrow

I was trying to finish installing the tfod api setup in my venv, then faced the following issue:

```
  -- Running cmake for pyarrow
  cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tfod\venv\Scripts\python.exe -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tfod\venv\Scripts\python.exe "" -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DPYARROW_BUILD_CUDA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_SUBSTRAIT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_FLIGHT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GANDIVA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ORC=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PLASMA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GCS=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_S3=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_HDFS=off -DPYARROW_USE_TENSORFLOW=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_BOOST=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DPYARROW_PARQUET_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hrduc58f\pyarrow_684de191ee6446dfaf83be823240de0a
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
    File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tfod\venv\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\tfod\\venv\\Scripts\\cmake.exe' failed with exit code 1
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: 'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tfod\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tfod\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4yy68iaa'
  cwd: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hrduc58f\pyarrow_684de191ee6446dfaf83be823240de0a
  Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Successfully built object-detection
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tfod\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tfod\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tfod\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 426, in run
    raise InstallationError(
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Remote version of pip: 23.1
Local version of pip:  23.1
Was pip installed by pip? True
Removed build tracker: 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tracker-t_z42dfc'
```

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: i am using 3.11 and vs code virtual enviorment

Comment: There aren't that many wheels available for arrow with python 3.11 (see here  https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/#files). So it's likely you'll have to compile arrow from source, which is not easy and requires a lot of dependencies to be installed.

Comment: can you please specify the dependencies and what needs to be done.

Comment: It's explained here but I would not go down that route, it takes a lot of time an effort. You're better off downgrading to python 3.10 and use available wheels. https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html#installing-from-source

Comment: so do i erase everything and then redo tfoda setup using python env 3.10